# unable to fetch some archives 404 not found

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 -y
```

This is the output:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 libonig2
  libperl4-corelibs-perl libqdbm14 lsof php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom php-pear php5-user-cache openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  liblua5.1-0 libonig2 libperl4-corelibs-perl libqdbm14 lsof php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,773 kB/6,774 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libapr1 armhf 1.5.1-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1 armhf 1.5.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 armhf 1.5.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-ldap armhf 1.5.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua5.1-0 armhf 5.1.5-7.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-bin armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u3
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-utils armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u3
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-data all 2.4.10-10+deb8u3
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2 armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u3
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libonig2 armhf 5.9.5-3.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libperl4-corelibs-perl all 0.003-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main lsof armhf 4.86+dfsg-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libqdbm14 armhf 1.8.78-5+b1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main php5-common armhf 5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main php5-json armhf 1.3.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main php5-cli armhf 5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libapache2-mod-php5 armhf 5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main php5-readline armhf 5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main ssl-cert all 1.0.35
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua5.1/liblua5.1-0_5.1.5-7.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.10-10+deb8u3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.10-10+deb8u3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-10+deb8u3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libo/libonig/libonig2_5.9.5-3.2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libp/libperl4-corelibs-perl/libperl4-corelibs-perl_0.003-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lsof/lsof_4.86+dfsg-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/q/qdbm/libqdbm14_1.8.78-5+b1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php-json/php5-json_1.3.6-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-readline_5.6.13+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.0.35_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.165 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

And yes, I have done this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

I have also done this:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is what my sources file looks like:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

I've been googling this problem for a couple of hours now, I still can't seem to find a fix! I'm VERY new to this, so I don't really know what to do.

**Edit:**
Tried this:

input:

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armh‌​f.deb
```

output:

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armh‌​f.deb
--2015-10-24 14:38:26--  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armh%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bf.deb
Resolving mirrordirector.raspbian.org (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)... 5.153.225.207, 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11
Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)|5.153.225.207|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-10-24 14:38:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Please can you try `wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armhf.deb` and add the output to your question. Apt's error reporting sucks.

Comment: @PeterGreen Done, i have updated my question.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I ran into a similar issue with this command:
**sudo apt-get install apache2 -y** after the error, I tried the recommended switch (which also fails):
**sudo apt-get install apache2 -y --fix-missing**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note: this post is based on information from the second revision of the question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/37597/2 )

Ok, this turned out to be a bad mirror, i've told the mirror redirection system not to use it and am following up with it's operator.