# Bad mirror when installing package

Tags: raspbian, apt

According to this post [unable to fetch some archives 404 not found](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/unable-to-fetch-some-archives-404-not-found), running `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 -y` won't work because of a bad mirror. I get the same errors.

How can I install a package when this is happening? Is it possible to install it from another place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another mirror by adding a line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` like this:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

Replacing `ftp.de.debian.org/debian` with the mirror in question. A list of available mirrors can be found at https://www.debian.org/mirror/list.

After that run `sudo apt-get update` and the next time you try to install the package it should work.